# How to export to Trainz (2019)?

Tags: export, add-on

How do I export a model from Blender 3.0 to Trainz when the Add-on isn’t working? It says an upgrade to 2.8 is required but I’m working with 3.0.

Comment: It looks like 3.0 broke the exporter, so the best you can do is find a Trainz forum and ask there.  Unfortunately it looks like nobody has worked on the exported for < 5 years, so it might be that you're out of luck.  Have you tried 2.93LTS?

Comment: Hi :). You no longer need any addon to export models for Trainz 2019. [Check the manual](https://online.ts2009.com/mediaWiki/index.php/HowTo/Export_from_Blender_using_FBX#Add_the_Material_and_Textures)